# Warning: Permission Denied, While clearing the cache

Tags: files

When I clear the cache of the site, I get lot of warnings with

> "Permission denied in drupal_unlink() (line 2199 of home/public_html/sitename/includes/file.inc)."

And I am unable to upload any default image to the site with the warning

> "File Could not be uploaded"

Comment: Make sure your permissions are set correctly for the specified folders mentioned in the errors. The web server must have permission to edit the files in the folders (user is usually something like www-data).

Comment: You could also be **out of space** .

Comment: Are you doing this from the UI or from drush?

Comment: I am doing this from the UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `temp` folder under "admin > config > media > file system": It should be writeable.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The permission for the tmp folder is set to 777

Comment: check its path.

Comment: sites/default/files/tmp . This is the path

Comment: give this path in "Temporary directory" as in image.

Comment: This doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Curious why this answer is accepted, based on the above comments?

Answer (score 1):

If write permission set already but still not resolve this, try manually delete all files (.css) in "sites\default\files\colorizer" folder first, then Clear Cache again! I have done sucessfully in my Windows 7 OS.

Regards

Chungph

Answer (score 1):

I know an answers already been accepted, but I wanted to add that I found (weirdly) that clearing my browser cache also fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used nginx and this issue was just related to wrong nginx configurations. This token parameter was totally ignored by Drupal:

```
https://[DRUPAL-URL]/admin/flush?token=[GET-PARAMETER]
```

So the token became empty and it caused the "permission denied" issue.
To fix that, I changed the nginx configuration to this:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
```

Seems that resolved the problem for me.